# HTML5 video playing after setting source

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html5-video

I'm trying to share html5 video using Node.js.

I have browser A with video url and browser B without it. I connect both using web-sockets and node.js. So far I'm getting and setting the video source from A to B. but when I try to play it in B using a new command is not working.

It is like the video is not loaded. So I'm using next code so that not get an error:

```
$('#v').on('loadeddata', function () {  
   if (v.readyState != 0) {  
      $("#v").get(0).play();  
   } else {
      $('#v').on('loadedmetadata', function () {
         $("#v").get(0).play();
      });
   }        
});
```

I set source on load page and later I press play on A and send the order to B. However it starts playing when another event occurs.

I used JQuery and Javascript load function trying to solve it but I couldn't get it works:

```
$("#v").get(0).load();

and

var v = document.getElementById('v'); 
v.load();
```

Any idea? how to really load the video ones you set the source?

I'm using Chrome (V.32) and Firefox (v.26).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have the video element set up, you may not be receiving the `loadeddata` event for a while, in which case it will not play right away, if ever. Fortunately, you don't need to wait for any of those events to start playing.

As soon as you've set the source URL, call `load` and then `play` right away. That should cause the browser to start loading and play it when its ready (unless you're on an iPad, in which case the user will need to click a play button).

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your answer. I couldn't get it works. video is there, source is set but then I get: "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable." when I set the currentTime.

Comment: You cannot set `currentTime` until you have a duration, so for that, you need to wait for the `loadedmetadata` or `durationchange` event, unless `v.readyState >= 1`.

Comment: I found the main problem, Websockets is calling 3 times the same function and on last time is not sending data, so it is setting the source to empty.

Thank you for your help.